# How to save 1 to many relation with Bookshelfjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

So i tried this

```
let Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({tableName: 'book'})
let User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user',
    books: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Book) // i have table book_user with user_id and book_id fk to respective tables
    }
})
return User
```

Then i tried to save using this snippet

```
models.User.forge(myUserObject).save()    
.then(function (user) {
    return user.books().attach(myBookArray)
})
```

But it didn't work as it expect the relation object (table `book_user`)

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using this snippet

```
return Promise.all([
    user: saveUser(),
    book: saveBook()
])
.then(function (result) {
    return result.user.books().attach([result.book.id])
})
```